# How to calculate power/energy taken by computer and screen

Tags: display, power-supply, power-consumption

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I calculate power consumption of my PC in Watt?](https://superuser.com/questions/123009/how-can-i-calculate-power-consumption-of-my-pc-in-watt)

I need to investigate how much power my Linux machine uses per week. I can take a look at the PSU but I would like to know how to calculate the average use of power it takes.

I also need to know how much power a CRT screen use per week.

Do I need to check the PSU Watt unit and Screen Watt usage and just add both to have the results?

P.S. My question is not related to: [How to choose a UPS / calculate power for a new PC](https://superuser.com/questions/9946/how-to-choose-a-ups-calculate-power-for-a-new-pc)

Comment: possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/123009/how-can-i-calculate-power-consumption-of-my-pc-in-watt

Comment: All of them are not related to my question. Maybe I was not clear but I need to know how to calculate, with the Watt info of my PSU, the average use of it for a week.

Comment: the answers to [123009](http://superuser.com/questions/123009/how-can-i-calculate-power-consumption-of-my-pc-in-watt) are exactly the answers that you will receive here.

Comment: My bad. I did not read 123009 completely. Thanks for the info. I have to say that I bought the Kill a Watt thing...

Comment: that's ok, it was in rough shape and had been incorrectly closed-as-dupe of the calculate-power-supply-capacity questions.  hopefully it's a little better now; thanks for making me take another look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [Kill A Watt](http://www.p3international.com/products/special/P4400/P4400-CE.html) or similar device. Just plug it in and set it to display total kWh.

Comment: I have a Kill A Watt. It works great, and it's cheaper than other name brand alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do it is to measure the power - you can get cheap power meters these days for 10 - 20 Euros (or USD). Measure the power at idling and when the computer is busy. Then convert this to total kWh per week or whatever.