# Measuring Intel Atom total power consumption

Tags: cpu, gpu, power-consumption, intel-atom

I have Intel Atom notebook with integrated Intel HD graphics. I want to measure total CPU + GPU wattage while running a game. To do so I'm using RTSS + HWInfo. There are CPU Package Power and GT Cores Power options in HWInfo. Do I have to check **only** CPU Package Power or sum up CPU Package Power and GT Cores Power to get my total CPU + GPU consumption?

**UPD:** In in-game load CPU Package Power is 6w while GT Cores Power is 5w. So is total Atom SoC power equal to 6 + 5 = 11w or is it 6w because CPU Package Power is total? And anyway why is it several times more than SDP from [Atom official specs](https://ark.intel.com/products/93362/Intel-Atom-x7-Z8750-Processor-2M-Cache-up-to-2-56-GHz-)?

Comment: Temperature might give a good, though indirect, idea of power usage. Or for "watts from the wall" power, could try a kill-a-watt meter or clone and some averaging of power used over say an hour or two, gaming vs not

Comment: @Xen2050 - Measuring the amount of wattage a laptop consumes when it’s charging does not indicate how much wattage it’s using on battery.  You would be easier to just establish the amount of wattage the CPU and GPU consumes at 100%. However, author, didn’t provide that clear information required to do so.

Comment: @Ramhound the battery definitely interferes, that's why the averaging over a longer time idea (start already charged, game, charge again...), still just a rough idea at best. Removing the battery might be an option but might also limit performance.

Comment: @Ramhound Just to be clear: I'm interested only in Atom SoC real wattage, not in laptop total consumption (which is obviously bigger) and not in battery lifespan as well.

Comment: @JustLogin - You have not provided enough information to answer your question.  The best we can do is indicate the total consumer possible by both your GPU and CPU.

Comment: [How can I calculate power consumption of my PC in Watt?](https://superuser.com/questions/123009/how-can-i-calculate-power-consumption-of-my-pc-in-watt)